# Session disappears on pages

Tags: php, session

I am having problems with keeping a session active in the home directory of my website.

I have a file named `login.php` where the session is set. Then if I navigate to `index.php` and do `print_R($_SESSION)`, it prints it. Then I go to `gallery.php` and it is gone. Same is true in reverse order: it appears if I go to `gallery.php` first, then disappears in `index.php`.

I'm thinking it might be the `php.ini` related.

edit:
Ok I figured out it was an included file that was causing this, its included on both pages, called 'nav.php'

```
<?php 
session_start();
$logout = intval($_GET['logout']);
if(isset($logout)){
session_destroy();
//header('Location: '$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

}
echo '<a href="/index.php" title ="home" class="navbutton">home</a>

<a href="/gallery.php" title ="gallery"class="navbutton">gallery</a>
 <a href="/info.php"title ="info"class="navbutton">info</a>

<a href="/contact.php"title="contact"class="navbutton">contact</a>';

if(isset($_SESSION['names']) || isset($_SESSION['guestlogin'])){echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?logout=1" title="logout"class="navbutton">logout</a>';
echo'<a href="/gallery" title ="gallery"class="navbutton"> test gallery</a>';

}
else{echo '<a href="/login" title="login"class="navbutton">login</a>';
}
echo'<a href="/blog"title ="blog"class="navbutton">blog</a>

<a href="/prints"title ="prints"class="navbutton">prints</a>';?>
```

could it be b/c it has session_destroy in it or something? Also are all included files supposed to have a session_start on them?

Comment: We could help if you post the code for gallery.php

Comment: Perhaps something wrong with your code.

Comment: my guess would be that gallery.php is missing session_start()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$logout = intval($_GET['logout']);
if(isset($logout)) {
  session_destroy();  
}
```

Do you see a problem here? `$logout` always *has* some value. No matter what the value is. So `isset($logout)` is always `TRUE`. Change it to:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout']) {
  session_destroy();  
}
```

This will logout user if he followed URL with `logout=1` in query string.

Comment: Cool thanks. I guess I thought it would be false if there wasnt a get variable. Now I know